# How do I change the global stylesheet of Safari from the command line on OS X?

Tags: macos, safari, defaults

I am looking for a command line solution to change Safari default stylesheet.

This can be configured manually by going to Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Style sheets.

Still, I need this in order to be able to reconfigure a system or deploy the settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've set a stylesheet in Safari and these are the changes that occurred in Safari's plist:

```
UserStyleSheetEnabled = 1;
UserStyleSheetLocationURLString = "~/Desktop/dsa.css";
WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey = "~/Desktop/dsa.css";
```

Your command line would be:

```
defaults write com.apple.safari UserStyleSheetEnabled 1 && defaults write com.apple.safari UserStyleSheetLocationURLString "/path/to/css" && defaults write com.apple.safari WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey 1 && defaults write com.apple.safari WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey "/path/to/css"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just integrated the solution to my my code https://github.com/bedouin/bedouin